# How to retrieve a sub-set of geometric primitives within arbitrary region?

Tags: regions

### Description

I have a geometric configuration consisting of a set of geometric primitives e.g. points and lines. I want to define an area and retrieve all points and lines which are members of its region.

### Example

Green is the area denoting the arbitrary region. I am after the points and lines within its boundaries.

[image: Geometry]

These are the points and lines within the region above.

[image: Points and Lines within Arbitrary Region]

Here is my attempt to solve the problem.

### Code

```
Module[
    {module, lines, points, area},

    (*Module Variable Declaration*)
    module = {{0,0},{0,43},{11,43},{11,45},{15,45},{15,44},{26,44},{26,39},{38,39},{38,34},{50,34},{50,37},{80,37},{80,33},{89,33},{89,4},{75,4},{75,0}};
    points = {{9,32},{6,25},{20,27},{25,23},{25,32},{33,29},{32,23},{37,24},{6,18},{10,9},{19,10},{22,9},{21,17},{23,14},{28,11},{27,18},{36,2},{34,15},{56,30},{68,30},{79,31},{60,25},{60,23},{62,22},{65,25},{72,24},{78,24},{83,21},{58,15},{57,13},{58,11},{59,7},{65,13},{67,19},{75,19},{78,13},{82,16},{68,8}};
    lines = {{{16,42},{25,42}},{{16,39},{25,39}},{{17,37},{17,22}},{{7,30},{7,23}},{{23,32},{23,22}},{{4,34},{30,34}}, {{8,18},{8,8}},{{13,30},{13,8}},{{18,18},{18,8}},{{30,32},{30,11}},{{38,32},{38,6}},{{42,32},{42,6}},{{15,4},{39,4}},{{46,28},{55,35}},{{56,35},{78,35}},{{56,28},{79,28}},{{48,24},{48,12}},{{52,28},{52,10}},{{47,3},{60,3}},{{42,5.5},{62,5.5}},{{47,8.5},{67,8.5}}};

    (*Arbitrary Region*)
    area = {{0,0},{0,43},{11,43},{11,45},{15,45},{15,44},{26,44},{26,39},{38,39},{38,34},{38,0}};

    (*Program*)
    Graphics[{
        {FaceForm @ White, EdgeForm @ {Thick, Gray},Polygon @ module},
        {RGBColor["#339989"], Opacity @ .8, Polygon @ area},
        Point @ points,
        Line @ lines
        }
    ]

    (* Example of all 'points' and 'lines' within 'area'*)
    (*RegionPlot @ (RegionIntersection[Polygon @ area, #] & /@ {Point @ points, Line @ lines})*)
]
```

I used `RegionPlot` to visualzie the points and lines deduced after `RegionIntersection`. However, I cannot retrieve the actual point and line definitions, and if I execute `RegionInteresection` on its own, the method fails to workout the lines. It also seems to take <10~20 sec to execute :s

I would appreciate communities thoughts on the above, and accept an answer which would solve the above problem. The faster the solution the better. Note, I need a generic solution which could be applied to similar compositions.

### Reference

[RegionIntersection](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed in M11.2. In M11.1 [`RegionIntersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection) of a polygon and line didn't simplify. For example (in M11.1):

```
RegionIntersection[
    Polygon[{{0,0},{0,43},{11,43},{11,45},{15,45},{15,44},{26,44},{26,39},{38,39},{38,34},{38,0}}],
    Line[{{15,4}, {39,4}}]
]
```

> RegionIntersection[Line[{{15, 4}, {39, 4}}], 
>    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 43}, {11, 43}, {11, 45}, {15, 45}, {15, 44}, {26, 
>       44}, {26, 39}, {38, 39}, {38, 34}, {38, 0}}]]

The same expression in M11.2:

```
RegionIntersection[
    Polygon[{{0,0},{0,43},{11,43},{11,45},{15,45},{15,44},{26,44},{26,39},{38,39},{38,34},{38,0}}],
    Line[{{15,4}, {39,4}}]
]
```

> Line[{{{15, 4}, {38, 4}}}]

This means your original code now basically works:

```
Module[
    {module, lines, points, area},

    (*Module Variable Declaration*)
    module = {{0,0},{0,43},{11,43},{11,45},{15,45},{15,44},{26,44},{26,39},{38,39},{38,34},{50,34},{50,37},{80,37},{80,33},{89,33},{89,4},{75,4},{75,0}};
    points = {{9,32},{6,25},{20,27},{25,23},{25,32},{33,29},{32,23},{37,24},{6,18},{10,9},{19,10},{22,9},{21,17},{23,14},{28,11},{27,18},{36,2},{34,15},{56,30},{68,30},{79,31},{60,25},{60,23},{62,22},{65,25},{72,24},{78,24},{83,21},{58,15},{57,13},{58,11},{59,7},{65,13},{67,19},{75,19},{78,13},{82,16},{68,8}};
    lines = {{{16,42},{25,42}},{{16,39},{25,39}},{{17,37},{17,22}},{{7,30},{7,23}},{{23,32},{23,22}},{{4,34},{30,34}}, {{8,18},{8,8}},{{13,30},{13,8}},{{18,18},{18,8}},{{30,32},{30,11}},{{38,32},{38,6}},{{42,32},{42,6}},{{15,4},{39,4}},{{46,28},{55,35}},{{56,35},{78,35}},{{56,28},{79,28}},{{48,24},{48,12}},{{52,28},{52,10}},{{47,3},{60,3}},{{42,5.5},{62,5.5}},{{47,8.5},{67,8.5}}};

    (*Arbitrary Region*)
    area = {{0,0},{0,43},{11,43},{11,45},{15,45},{15,44},{26,44},{26,39},{38,39},{38,34},{38,0}};

    (*Program*)
    Graphics[{
        {FaceForm @ White, EdgeForm @ {Thick, Gray},Polygon @ module},
        {RGBColor["#339989"], Opacity @ .8, Polygon @ area},
        Point @ points,
        Line @ lines
        }
    ];

    (* Example of all 'points' and 'lines' within 'area'*)
    RegionIntersection[Polygon @ area, #] & /@ {Point @ points, Line @ lines}
]
```

> {Point[{{9, 32}, {6, 25}, {20, 27}, {25, 23}, {25, 32}, {33, 29}, {32, 
>       23}, {37, 24}, {6, 18}, {10, 9}, {19, 10}, {22, 9}, {21, 17}, {23, 
>       14}, {28, 11}, {27, 18}, {36, 2}, {34, 15}}], 
>    Line[{{{16., 42.}, {25., 42.}}, {{16., 39.}, {25., 39.}}, {{17., 34.}, {17., 
>        37.}}, {{17., 34.}, {17., 22.}}, {{17., 34.}, {4., 34.}}, {{17., 
>        34.}, {30., 34.}}, {{7., 23.}, {7., 30.}}, {{23., 22.}, {23., 
>        32.}}, {{8., 8.}, {8., 18.}}, {{13., 8.}, {13., 30.}}, {{18., 8.}, {18., 
>        18.}}, {{30., 11.}, {30., 32.}}, {{38., 6.}, {38., 32.}}, {{15., 
>        4.}, {38., 4.}}}]}

Answer (score 3):

```
Module[{module, lines, points, area, region, pointsinout, linesinout,
memberpoints, lineswithin, indexshared, func, posTrue, thread, 
linesoutside},

module = {{0, 0}, {0, 43}, {11, 43}, {11, 45}, {15, 45}, {15, 
44}, {26, 44}, {26, 39}, {38, 39}, {38, 34}, {50, 34}, {50, 
37}, {80, 37}, {80, 33}, {89, 33}, {89, 4}, {75, 4}, {75, 0}};

points = {{9, 32}, {6, 25}, {20, 27}, {25, 23}, {25, 32}, {33, 
29}, {32, 23}, {37, 24}, {6, 18}, {10, 9}, {19, 10}, {22, 9}, {21,
 17}, {23, 14}, {28, 11}, {27, 18}, {36, 2}, {34, 15}, {56, 
30}, {68, 30}, {79, 31}, {60, 25}, {60, 23}, {62, 22}, {65, 
25}, {72, 24}, {78, 24}, {83, 21}, {58, 15}, {57, 13}, {58, 
11}, {59, 7}, {65, 13}, {67, 19}, {75, 19}, {78, 13}, {82, 
16}, {68, 8}};

lines = {{{16, 42}, {25, 42}}, {{16, 39}, {25, 39}}, {{17, 37}, {17, 
 22}}, {{7, 30}, {7, 23}}, {{23, 32}, {23, 22}}, {{4, 34}, {30, 
 34}}, {{8, 18}, {8, 8}}, {{13, 30}, {13, 8}}, {{18, 18}, {18, 
 8}}, {{30, 32}, {30, 11}}, {{38, 32}, {38, 6}}, {{42, 32}, {42, 
 6}}, {{15, 4}, {39, 4}}, {{46, 28}, {55, 35}}, {{56, 35}, {78, 
 35}}, {{56, 28}, {79, 28}}, {{48, 24}, {48, 12}}, {{52, 28}, {52,
  10}}, {{47, 3}, {60, 3}}, {{42, 5.5}, {62, 5.5}}, {{47, 
 8.5}, {67, 8.5}}};

(*Arbitrary Region*)
area = {{0, 0}, {0, 43}, {11, 43}, {11, 45}, {15, 45}, {15, 44}, {26,
 44}, {26, 39}, {38, 39}, {38, 34}, {38, 0}};

region = Polygon[area];
pointsinout = RegionMember[region, points]; 
linesinout = RegionMember[region, lines];

memberpoints = Pick[points, pointsinout, True];
lineswithin = Pick[lines, And @@@ linesinout, True];
linesoutside = Pick[lines, linesinout, {False, False}] /. {} :> Sequence[];

indexshared = Flatten@Position[linesinout, {True, False} | {False, True}];

posTrue = 
Cases[linesinout, {True, False} | {False, True}] /. {{True,False} :> 1, {False, True} :> 2};

thread = Thread[{indexshared, posTrue}];

func[list_, x_, posT_] := Module[{n, n1, n2, p, sharedline , f},
sharedline = lines[[x]];

Which[posT == 1, p = First@sharedline, posT == 2, p = Last@sharedline];

n = {n1, n2};

n = n /. 
 Maximize[
   EuclideanDistance[p, n], {n \[Element] region, 
    n \[Element] Line[sharedline]}][[2]];

f[1] := (AppendTo[lineswithin, {First@sharedline, n}];
 AppendTo[linesoutside, {n, Last@sharedline}]);  
f[2] := (AppendTo[lineswithin, {n, Last@sharedline}];
 AppendTo[linesoutside, {First@sharedline, n}]);

f[posT];
lineswithin
];

lineswithin = Fold[func[#1, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]] &, lineswithin, thread];

Graphics[{{FaceForm@White, EdgeForm@{Thick, Gray}, 
Polygon@module}, {RGBColor["#339989"], Opacity@.8, 
Polygon@area}, {Blue, PointSize[0.015], Point@memberpoints}, {Red, 
Line@lineswithin}, {Red, 
Point@Complement[points, memberpoints]}, {Darker@Green, 
Line@linesoutside}}]
]
```

Notice the image (the line is clearly cut into two parts, with the long one (red) inside the region and the small portion in green outside):
[image]

Comment: @e.doroskevic I have updated the answer.

Comment: Hey Ali, upvoted for the work, and will accept it as an answer if nothing else comes up. I am looking for a generic solution

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative Solution

The code is an example of a solution I used to derive geometric primitives within arbitrary region. Two methods are used; the first method to derive points, and the second method is used to derive lines. The implementation does have its issues as stated below, and is not the most elegant solution but it works. Ideally, I was looking for a single method that would encapsulate the desired operation.

```
Module[
 {
 module, lines, points, area1, area2,area3, 
 renderRegion,getRegionPoints, getRegionLines
 },
                                
 (*Variable Declaration*)
 module = {{0, 0}, {0, 43}, {11, 43}, {11, 45}, {15, 45}, {15, 44}, {26, 44}, {26, 39}, {38, 39}, {38, 34}, {50, 34}, {50, 37}, {80, 37}, {80, 33}, {89, 33}, {89, 4}, {75, 4}, {75, 0}};
 points = {{9, 32}, {6, 25}, {20, 27}, {25, 23}, {25, 32}, {33, 29}, {32, 23}, {37, 24}, {6, 18}, {10, 9}, {19, 10}, {22, 9}, {21, 17}, {23, 14}, {28, 11}, {27, 18}, {36, 2}, {34, 15}, {56, 30}, {68, 30}, {79, 31}, {60, 25}, {60, 23}, {62, 22}, {65, 25}, {72, 24}, {78, 24}, {83, 21}, {58, 15}, {57, 13}, {58, 11}, {59, 7}, {65, 13}, {67, 19}, {75, 19}, {78, 13}, {82, 16}, {68, 8}};
 lines = {{{16, 42}, {25, 42}}, {{16, 39}, {25, 39}}, {{17, 37}, {17, 22}}, {{7, 30}, {7, 23}}, {{23, 32}, {23, 22}}, {{4, 34}, {30, 34}}, {{8, 18}, {8, 8}}, {{13, 30}, {13, 8}}, {{18, 18}, {18, 8}}, {{30, 32}, {30, 11}}, {{38, 32}, {38, 6}}, {{42, 32}, {42, 6}}, {{15, 4}, {39, 4}}, {{46, 28}, {55, 35}}, {{56, 35}, {78, 35}}, {{56, 28}, {79, 28}}, {{48, 24}, {48, 12}}, {{52, 28}, {52, 10}}, {{47, 3}, {60, 3}}, {{42, 5.5}, {62, 5.5}}, {{47, 8.5}, {67, 8.5}}};
 
 area1 = {{0, 0}, {0, 43}, {11, 43}, {11, 45}, {15, 45}, {15, 44}, {26, 44}, {26, 39}, {38, 39}, {38, 34}, {38, 0}};
 area2 = {{38, 0}, {38, 34}, {50, 34}, {50, 0}};
 area3 = {{50, 0}, {50, 37}, {80, 37}, {80, 33}, {89, 33}, {89, 4}, {75, 4}, {75, 0}};
 
 (*Functions Declaration*)  
 getRegionPoints[area_, points_] := RegionIntersection[Polygon @ area, Point @ points];
 getRegionLines[area_, lines_] := Select[
                                    RegionIntersection[
                                            Polygon @ area, 
                                            Point @ MeshCoordinates @ DiscretizeRegion[Line @ #, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 1}]
                                            ] & /@ lines
                                               /. Point -> Line, 
                                    Head @ # == Line &
                                ];

 renderRegion[rgb_, region_] := {RGBColor[rgb], Opacity @ .7, EdgeForm[{Thick, Darker @ Gray}], Polygon @ region};
 
 (*Program*)
 Graphics[{
      renderRegion["#ffffff", module],
      
      Point @ points,
      Line @ lines,
      
      renderRegion["#339989", area1],
      {Red, getRegionPoints[area1, points]},
      {Red, getRegionLines[area1, lines]},
      
      renderRegion["#003153", area2],
      {Yellow, getRegionLines[area2, lines]},
      
      renderRegion["#b08f81", area3],
      {Green, getRegionPoints[area3, points]},
      {Green, getRegionLines[area3, lines]}
   }]   
]
```

### Output

[image: working example]

### Issues

I.1 - If arbitrary region does not include any lines or points, the functions `getRegionPoints` and `getRegionLines` return `EmptyRegion` which does not render in `Graphics` crushing the program. Requires, modification of some sort to prevent such behaviour.

Comment: nice to see the solution. I posted another answer above as well. +1

Comment: Hey @Ali I think we cracked it )) i just wish `RegionIntersection` would have worked. This problem could have been trivial!

Answer (score 1):

This is the most general solution i could conceive.

**added the `SameQ` test in `Complement` to get lines outside the region as well**

```
Module[{module, lines, points, area, region, memberpoints, 
lineswithin,linesoutside},

module = {{0, 0}, {0, 43}, {11, 43}, {11, 45}, {15, 45}, {15, 
44}, {26, 44}, {26, 39}, {38, 39}, {38, 34}, {50, 34}, {50, 
37}, {80, 37}, {80, 33}, {89, 33}, {89, 4}, {75, 4}, {75, 0}};
points = {{9, 32}, {6, 25}, {20, 27}, {25, 23}, {25, 32}, {33, 
29}, {32, 23}, {37, 24}, {6, 18}, {10, 9}, {19, 10}, {22, 9}, {21,
 17}, {23, 14}, {28, 11}, {27, 18}, {36, 2}, {34, 15}, {56, 
30}, {68, 30}, {79, 31}, {60, 25}, {60, 23}, {62, 22}, {65, 
25}, {72, 24}, {78, 24}, {83, 21}, {58, 15}, {57, 13}, {58, 
11}, {59, 7}, {65, 13}, {67, 19}, {75, 19}, {78, 13}, {82, 
16}, {68, 8}};
lines = {{{16, 42}, {25, 42}}, {{16, 39}, {25, 39}}, {{17, 37}, {17, 
 22}}, {{7, 30}, {7, 23}}, {{23, 32}, {23, 22}}, {{4, 34}, {30, 
 34}}, {{8, 18}, {8, 8}}, {{13, 30}, {13, 8}}, {{18, 18}, {18, 
 8}}, {{30, 32}, {30, 11}}, {{38, 32}, {38, 6}}, {{42, 32}, {42, 
 6}}, {{15, 4}, {39, 4}}, {{46, 28}, {55, 35}}, {{56, 35}, {78, 
 35}}, {{56, 28}, {79, 28}}, {{48, 24}, {48, 12}}, {{52, 28}, {52,
  10}}, {{47, 3}, {60, 3}}, {{42, 5.5}, {62, 5.5}}, {{47, 
 8.5}, {67, 8.5}}};
 (*Arbitrary Region*)
 area = {{0, 0}, {0, 43}, {11, 43}, {11, 45}, {15, 45}, {15, 44}, {26,
 44}, {26, 39}, {38, 39}, {38, 34}, {38, 0}};
 region = Polygon[area];

 lineswithin = 
 Thread[RegionBounds[RegionIntersection[region, Line[#]]]] & /@ 
lines //Cases[#, {{_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ}, {_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ}}] &;

 memberpoints = (Transpose@RegionBounds[RegionIntersection[region,Point[#]]] & /@ 
  points) /. patt : {{_, _}, {_, _}} :> patt[[1]] // 
 Cases[#, {_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ}] &;

linesoutside = 
Complement[lines, lineswithin,
SameTest -> (#1[[1]] == #2[[1]] || #1[[1]] == #2[[2]] || #1[[2]] == #2[[2]] &)];

Graphics[{{FaceForm@White, EdgeForm@{Thick, Gray}, 
Polygon@module}, {RGBColor["#339989"], Opacity@.8, 
Polygon@area}, {Blue, PointSize[0.01], Point@memberpoints}, {Red,Line@lineswithin, 
Blue,Line@linesoutside}, {Green,PointSize[0.01],Point@Complement[points, memberpoints]}}]
]
```

[image]

with a change of `area` as given by the Alternative answer by @e.doroskevic

[image]